# How to add SoapEndPoint after server is started on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

I'm using simple console app to expose a soap web service. It works as expected.
Now i want to add another web service after the server is started. How to make it work?
I have following simple console application:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
            _App = host.Build();
            _App.UseRouting();
            _App.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISimpleServiceInterface>("/SimpleService.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
            });
            _App.Urls.Add("http://*:5000");
            _App.RunAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Server has been started successfully ...");

            AddNewService();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Server starts and i can access the wsdl http://localhost:5000/SimpleService.asmx?wsdl)
Now the AddNewService method simple try to define a new SoapEndPoint after service started.
Code looks like this:

```
        static private void AddNewService()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Wait 5 seconds to make sure web application is running
                Console.WriteLine("Adding new service ..."); // Add new Soap service now, after startup
                _App?.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISimpleServiceInterface2>("/SimpleService2.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Added new service.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to Add new service. Error=" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This works ok if first request to url is done after the service is created: (http://localhost:5000/SimpleService2.asmx?wsdl)
[image]

But if a request is sent before the service is created. Then any request done after the creation of the service will fail:
[image]
I'm guessing i need to raise some event or something to the web server to get it refreshed or something.
How can i do that?
Also is there a way to remove a SoapEndPoint once is has been defined/exposed?
Idea is basically being able to add/remove/update SoapEndPoint on the fly.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think maybe the order of execution is causing something to change, not following the response DTO naming convention and thus causing the SOAP endpoint not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Progess a little bit on this.
I basically need to register IActionDescriptorChangeProvider class to be able to notify the web application.
I also needed to slightly change my main routine.
Here is the main function:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
            host.Services.AddControllers();
            host.Services.AddSingleton<IActionDescriptorChangeProvider>(MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance);
            host.Services.AddSingleton(MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance);
            host.Services.AddSingleton<ISimpleServiceInterface, SimpleService>();

            _App = host.Build();
            _App.MapControllers();
            _App.UseRouting();

            _App.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISimpleServiceInterface>("/SimpleService.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
            });
            _App.Urls.Add("http://*:5000");
            _App.RunAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Server has been started successfully ...");

            AddNewService();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Then the AddService function (note the 2 lines added to make the notification):

```
        static private void AddNewService()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Wait 5 seconds to make sure web application is running
                Console.WriteLine("Adding new service ..."); // Add new Soap service now, after startup
                _App?.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISimpleServiceInterface2>("/SimpleService2.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
                });

                // Notify the web application of the changes
                MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance.HasChanged = true;
                MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance.TokenSource.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Added new service.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Failed to Add new service. Error=" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and class implementing IActionDescriptorChangeProvider:

```
    public class MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider : IActionDescriptorChangeProvider
    {
        public static MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider Instance { get; } = new MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider();

        public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; private set; } = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public bool HasChanged { get; set; }

        public IChangeToken GetChangeToken()
        {
            TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            return new CancellationChangeToken(TokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
```

Once you do that, it will work fine on the second request (wsdl request).
Problem is that the wsdl may be accessible but the function itself (route to the actual method on the singleton) is not there.
Registration of the singleton for ISimpleServiceInterface2 need to be done but not sure how to achieve this.
My end goal is to be able to add/remove/update soap web service after server is built.
Basically idea is to update the soap service with a newer assembly.
If anybody has some idea, comments, response, please post them here. That will be appreciated.